# SilverStripe: How to change count items per page for popup window UploadField?

Tags: silverstripe

When I click upload file on UploadField, it open dialog (admin/pages/edit/EditForm/field/Images/select) where my file show in paginated data grid. 
It show 8 file per page. 
How to change it to 20 file per page? 
Look at my screenshot [Upload file data grid](http://www.silverstripe.org/assets/forum/attachments/2014-10-12-19.39.00.png)

[UncleCheese](http://www.silverstripe.org/community/forums/general-questions/show/76406#post374680) gave the solution: 
Unfotunately, this setting is not configurable. The value of 8 is hardcoded on line 1604 of UploadField.php:

```
  $config->addComponent(new GridFieldPaginator(8));
```

it worked

Answer (score 1):

By the sound of it you already have your GridField, so this should suffice.

```
<?php 

//...

public function getCMSFields() {
    //... Add GridField $gridField
    
    $paginator = $gridField->getComponentByType('GridFieldPaginator');
    $paginator->setItemsPerPage(15); // Items per page.

    //... return FieldList
}

//...
```

API Docs: http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/source-class-GridFieldPaginator.html#258-264

Also, when you ask a question you should post the code you have so far otherwise its very difficult for anybody to answer it. I guess this is why you got a down vote.

Comment: I add code for my topic. But I think that your code is not for the part about which I asked. Look at the screenshot please: [link]http://www.silverstripe.org/assets/forum/attachments/2014-10-12-19.39.00.png[/link]. I add your code, and get error: [User Error] Uncaught Exception: Object->__call(): the method 'getcomponentbytype' does not exist on 'SortableUploadField'